# Build web application before or after deployment?

Tags: node.js, azure, heroku, deployment, kudu

#### Context

- Web application project has a `/build` (or `/dist`) folder with front-end files, generated during build (by [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)). This folder is not under the source control (see, for example: [React.js Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-stater-kit))
- The server-side code doesn't require bundling or compilation step, so the `/src` folder from your project can be deployed as it is (these source files are used to run Node.js or ASP.NET vNext server)
- Web application is deployed via Git (see Git-based deployment options in [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/) as an example)

#### Questions

1. Is it better to build (bundle and minify) front-end files before or after deployment?

   - If before, you may end-up having a separate repository (or branch), with the `/build` folder under the source control alongside with the rest of the project files. This repo is used solely for deployment purposes.
   - If after, the deployment time may increase - time needed to download additional npm modules used in the build process, the server's CPU may spike up to 100% during the build, potentially harming your web application's responsiveness.
2. Is it better to build front-end files on the remote server before or after running KuduSync command?
3. If you deploy your web application to Windows Azure with [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu), should the deployment script copy only the contents of the `/build` folder (with public, front-end files like .js, .html, .css) to `/wwwroot`? As opposed to copying all the project files (server-side source code and front-end bundles), which it does by default.
4. By default Azure's deployment script copies all the project files, from `D:\home\site\repository` folder to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` folder, and then Node.js app is started from there. Is it a necessary step? Why not to start the Node.js (or ASP.NET vNext) app from the `D:\home\site\repository` folder? And if it indeed should be copied to a separate folder, why source files are placed in `wwwroot`, maybe it's better to copy them to another folder, outside `wwwroot`?

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with both Azure and Heroku so I can't give any ideas about those specific deployment options.

I am using (4 dedicated servers with 2 of them solely for serving static files), the option to build the bundled and minified javascript files (for front-end) and add all those files to the main repository has several advantages

- You only need to run it once (either on your dev machine or on staging server, whatever way you want). This is particularly helpful when you have to run multiple static servers since you don't have to run the build command on each server. One might argue that they can use something like `Glusterfs` to synchronise files from one static server to all other servers and the build process only needs to be run once. However, it is a whole different story when it comes to this kind of setup
- It makes your deployment process simple, just pull new code and restart the server(s) if necessary (assuming that you have some mechanism to increase the static file version so that all your clients will receive the latest version)
- Avoid unnecessary dependencies on your production servers. This might sound weird for some people but I just don't want to install any extra libraries on my production servers unless they are absolutely necessary. With the build process run locally on my dev machine, my production servers only have what they need to run the production code and nothing else

However this approach also has some disadvantages:

- When more than one developer in your team (accidentally) run the build process and commit the code, then you will have a crazy list of conflicts. However, it can be solved by simply running the build process again after you merge all the changes from other guys. This is more about the workflow
- Your repository will be bigger. I personally don't think this is a big issue considering few extra MB of my bundled and minified files. If your front-end javascript is big enough for this to be an issue then it is another story